# Selecting fileds in mysql that have connections to all other given fileds

Tags: mysql

I am struggling with one SQL query that will enable me following scenario. Let we have one many-to-many table, for example:

ingridient - object

sugar - cake

milk - cake

milk - cookie

sugar - cookie

salt - dish

salt - cake
...

I need an SQL query thagt would enable me to select all objects that have ALL of ingridients. If i pass sugar and milk for example, i should get cake and cooke, if i pass milk, sugar and salt i should get only cake, etc..

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT object, GROUP_CONCAT(ingridient) AS ingredients
FROM (
    SELECT object, ingridient
    FROM tbl
    ORDER BY ingridient
) subQuery
GROUP BY object
HAVING ingredients = 'milk,salt,sugar'
```

However note that the ingredients list you provide for the HAVING clause would have to be ordered alphabetically.